# React Component to render children conditionally not working as I want it to

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom React Component that I made to render loading and error states conditionally, this is the code:

```
const StateHandler = ({ requestData, children }) => {
  return requestData.loading
    ? <LoadingIndicator />
    : requestData.error
    ? <ErrorMessage />
    : requestData.done && children;
};
```

It receives an object like this:

```
const requestData = {
  loading: false, //or true
  error: false, //or true
  done: false //or true
}
```

It works, but it has a problem, suppose I use it from another component, like this:

```
return (
    <>
        <> ... some other stuff </>
        <StateHandler requestData={requestData}>
          <>
            <p>{user.name}</p>
          </>
        </StateHandler>
    </>
)
```

The problem is, the variable `user` will be undefined until its populated with data from an API, and `{user.name}` will throw "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Is there any way to prevent the children being evaluated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a variable isLoaded = false and set it to true when after fetching data. Render component only if isLoaded true

Answer (score 1):

No there is not any way i think to prevent from children being evaluated but below can help you with the error:

```
return (
    <>
        <> ... some other stuff </>
        <StateHandler requestData={requestData}>
          <>
            <p>{user && user.name ? user.name : ""}</p>
          </>
        </StateHandler>
    </>
)
```

This way if user is undefined then it will skip evaluating and rendering `user.name` and instead would render nothing, and hence no error.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), you could keep the simplicity of your code with a slight change.

```js
return (
    <>
        <> ... some other stuff </>
        <StateHandler requestData={requestData}>
          <>
            <p>{user?.name}</p>
          </>
        </StateHandler>
    </>
)
```

If you can't use optional chaining, Sakshi's answer would be best.